# Node.js - How to install requestHandlers..?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am initiating a "stat" event using index.js file, I believe all my code are fine. when i start my server i am getting this issue..

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './requestHandlers'
```

here is my index.js:

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

I understand my "requestHandlers" - module is missing, how can i install that module? i do have the "npm" installed..

any one help me?

Comment: requestHandlers.js is created by you? If so where is your requestHandlers.js file located?

Comment: Refer this blog http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm

Comment: I am not create one, i thought i need to download from "npm", I am very starter just trying to learn.

Comment: In my knowledge there is no module named requestHandlers. But there is a module request. you can install that using the command "npm install request"

Comment: To install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
npm install (in package directory, no arguments)
Refer: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html
and search modules in https://npmjs.org/search?q=requestHandlers

Answer (score 0):

How about check the file name of "requestHandlers.js"
I meet this error by missing the 's' at the end of "requestHandlers".

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error by missing making "requestHandlers.js" file.

you need create "requestHandlers.js" file.

Check back to http://www.nodebeginner.org

Comment: You mean that you have forgotten to create the file `requestHandlers.js`?

Comment: yes. code : function start() {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
}

function upload() {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;

Answer (score -1):

Place lines 1 through 11, top of page 21, The Node Beginner book, in a file named requestHandlers.js.

Comment: Instead of redirecting others to a book, could you please include the necessary code in this answer?